How to loop through multiple cursors in succession in PL/SQL
This is probably simple but I cannot find a good example online. I have 5 cursors I would like to iterate through in succession (loop through all of cursor 1, then loop through all of cursor 2, etc). The caveat is that I (believe I) need to open all the cursors at the same time, because I am deleting records in the loops that would affect the output of the select statements in the latter cursors... I want the cursors to reflect the output at the beginning of the program's execution, not at the start of the loop for the cursor.
Example:
DECLARE 

CURSOR A IS SELECT * FROM tableA;
CURSOR B IS SELECT * FROM tableB;
CURSOR C IS SELECT * FROM tableC;

rowA A%rowtype;
rowB B%rowtype;
rowC C%rowtype;

BEGIN
 OPEN A;
 OPEN B;
 OPEN C;

 FOR record IN A LOOP
  FETCH A INTO rowA
  DELETE FROM ...
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE A;

 FOR record IN B LOOP
  FETCH B INTO rowB
  DELETE FROM ...
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE B;

 etc

END;




Trying the snippet above, I realized that specifying "FOR record IN X" is implicitly opening the cursor again, which throws an error. But if I don't add what cursor I would like to loop through, how would the loop know which cursor I am trying to loop through since I have 3 cursors open?
Again, I need to open all the cursors before the loops because I am deleting rows in the loops that affect what the cursors' select statements would return. By the time cursor C's loop is reached, the cursor would return no rows if I open it at that time, which is not what I want.

FOR ... IN ... implicitly opens and closes cursors, as well as fetches each row until it reaches the last row. You don't mix that with explicit OPEN, CLOSE commands. Those are used only when you want to use your own manual loop testing and fetching. Also, you can simplify by bypassing the formal declaration of those cursors entirely and simply embed the cursor SQL in the for ... in ([sql]) clause.

What are the conditions for deleting rows? You might be able to write it in normal SQL instead of using cursors.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; a complete example of your DELETE queries; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement; and the expected contents of the tables after running your PL/SQL block.

Looks like you will have to do it old-school, explicitly opening them all at the start, then iterating through each cursor in a bare loop that has a fetch statement and an exit condition when the particular cursor is not found. That way they should all show query results as of the start of the program execution. Without testing, I don't know what Oracle does when you delete from a table that is in your open cursor's base query--hopefully, for your case, the open cursor uses undo to see the state of data as of when it was opened. Sounds like a small test is in order.

Oracle won't necessarily read all the rows for each cursor upon opening. If you have deleted rows in one loop and then try to read them in another, you will get an exception. If it has read the rows and you try to delete an already deleted row, you will get another exception.

This example is  based on Scott's sample EMP and DEPT tables. There are two cursors; one of them displays departments and deletes employees who work in these departments. Another one displays (or, is-trying-to display) employees.
Sample data:
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> select deptno, dname from dept order by deptno;

    DEPTNO DNAME
---------- --------------
        10 ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH
        30 SALES
        40 OPERATIONS

SQL> select deptno, empno, ename from emp order by deptno, ename;

    DEPTNO      EMPNO ENAME
---------- ---------- ----------
        10       7782 CLARK
        10       7839 KING
        10       7934 MILLER
        20       7876 ADAMS
        20       7902 FORD
        20       7566 JONES
        20       7788 SCOTT
        20       7369 SMITH
        30       7499 ALLEN
        30       7698 BLAKE
        30       7900 JAMES
        30       7654 MARTIN
        30       7844 TURNER
        30       7521 WARD

14 rows selected.

In the first example, I'm opening - and then dealing with - cursors one-by-one (lines #9 and 20):
SQL> declare
  2    cursor cur_d is select deptno, dname from dept order by deptno;
  3    cur_dr cur_d%rowtype;
  4
  5    cursor cur_e is select deptno, empno, ename from emp
  6      order by deptno, ename;
  7    cur_er cur_e%rowtype;
  8  begin
  9    open cur_d;
 10    dbms_output.put_line('Departments ----------');
 11    loop
 12      fetch cur_d into cur_dr;
 13      exit when cur_d%notfound;
 14      dbms_output.put_line(cur_dr.deptno ||' - '|| cur_dr.dname);
 15      delete from emp where deptno = cur_dr.deptno;
 16      dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || sql%rowcount ||' employees');
 17    end loop;
 18    close cur_d;
 19
 20    open cur_e;
 21    dbms_output.put_line('Employees ----------');
 22    loop
 23      fetch cur_e into cur_er;
 24      exit when cur_e%notfound;
 25      dbms_output.put_line(cur_er.deptno ||' - '|| cur_er.ename);
 26    end loop;
 27    close cur_e;
 28  end;
 29  /

Output shows list of departments and number of employees I deleted. However, there are no employees displayed at all because they are deleted before cur_e is opened:
Departments ----------
10 - ACCOUNTING
Deleted 3 employees
20 - RESEARCH
Deleted 5 employees
30 - SALES
Deleted 6 employees
40 - OPERATIONS
Deleted 0 employees
Employees ----------

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

As the final result, the emp table is empty:
SQL> select deptno, ename from emp order by deptno, ename;

no rows selected

SQL>


Another example opens both cursors at the beginning (lines #9 and 10):
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.

SQL> declare
  2    cursor cur_d is select deptno, dname from dept order by deptno;
  3    cur_dr cur_d%rowtype;
  4
  5    cursor cur_e is select deptno, empno, ename from emp
  6      order by deptno, ename;
  7    cur_er cur_e%rowtype;
  8  begin
  9    open cur_d;
 10    open cur_e;
 11    dbms_output.put_line('Departments ----------');
 12    loop
 13      fetch cur_d into cur_dr;
 14      exit when cur_d%notfound;
 15      dbms_output.put_line(cur_dr.deptno ||' - '|| cur_dr.dname);
 16      delete from emp where deptno = cur_dr.deptno;
 17      dbms_output.put_line('Deleted ' || sql%rowcount ||' employees');
 18    end loop;
 19    close cur_d;
 20
 21    dbms_output.put_line('Employees ----------');
 22    loop
 23      fetch cur_e into cur_er;
 24      exit when cur_e%notfound;
 25      dbms_output.put_line(cur_er.deptno ||' - '|| cur_er.ename);
 26    end loop;
 27    close cur_e;
 28  end;
 29  /

Departments are displayed as previously,  employees are deleted, but they are also displayed because cur_e was opened before deleting employees:
Departments ----------
10 - ACCOUNTING
Deleted 3 employees
20 - RESEARCH
Deleted 5 employees
30 - SALES
Deleted 6 employees
40 - OPERATIONS
Deleted 0 employees

Here are all the employees:
Employees ----------
10 - CLARK
10 - KING
10 - MILLER
20 - ADAMS
20 - FORD
20 - JONES
20 - SCOTT
20 - SMITH
30 - ALLEN
30 - BLAKE
30 - JAMES
30 - MARTIN
30 - TURNER
30 - WARD

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

The final result is just the same: the emp table is empty:
SQL> select deptno, ename from emp order by deptno, ename;

no rows selected

SQL>

